Freezer not freezing
My freezer stopped freezing. We moved it to garage because the refrigerator side worked. After moving the freezer is now working. Why?

The movement either knock something(valve/sensor) sticking loose, or connected something(wire/connection) that was loose.  Had an old ATV like that.  stopped working working out in the field.  After some time of it it not starting/working, towed it back over bumby fields.  Boosted the battery and it work perfectly.

Yeah I'd imagine something was knocked will moving it stopping it from working. That could been the issue that caused the other issue with the refrigerator side. I'd check if power is been drawn correctly from the outlet too and if the fuse in the plug is still working too just to be sure.
